Authorative opinion on swaddling
In the past when a decision on parenting was needed, I usually looked for an authorative source. For example by following the Dutch Health Service we decided to give 1 shot, but not another.
However, despite searching I have not found an authorative source with a recommendation on whether to swaddle.
I am not looking for opinions, or explanations on pros/cons or context of how often it is being done. I am also not looking fot information on how (not) to do it. I am simply looking for guidance from an authorative source. It could be a yes/no or a basic decision tree.

Ideally the source would be a country or regional organization (e.g. WHO,NHS,...) responsible for health advice. A research is always done with a specific scope, so university recommendations would come in at a lower point for me.
Best would be from The Netherlands, but if not that is fine.
If there are multiple conflicting guidelines from the most relevant authorities that would be good to know as well.

You may not have found any authoritative guidelines on swaddling because it isn't considered a controversial or risky practice, and as far as I'm aware it has no negative effects at all.
In a nutshell, swaddling mimics the compactness and comfort of the womb, and helps ease the transition of a newborn into a world outside of the womb. It helps them feel secure for the first few months of their life.
However, you may want to do some reading on when to stop swaddling. It's been a while for us so my memory is fuzzy, but once your baby has the strength to move around you wouldn't want them to roll over without the ability to get out of the swaddle.
With all of this being said: authoritative guidelines may exist, but if they do I've never seen them. I did get quite a bit of help from the NHS in the UK when our kids were younger, so the following links may be useful for you:
https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/baby/caring-for-a-newborn/reduce-the-risk-of-sudden-infant-death-syndrome/
https://www.lullabytrust.org.uk/safer-sleep-advice/product-information/swaddling-slings/

I agree with you, there is no authoritative literature on whether or not to swaddle. But wow, is it wonderful! The position the American Academy of Pediatrics takes is, literally, "The AAP recommends that parents swaddle their baby if they would like to."

It may not be considered controversial depending on where you live. As far as I can see it is well embraced in the US and less so in Europe. Every site I check says 'this is how you can minimize risks' so though there are benefits there are clearly risks as well.

There is essentially no risk if you use common sense and take the time to read basic guidelines. But websites will talk about minimizing risk because, unfortunately, many parents have no common sense and will do dumb things unless you give them explicit instruction not to. Just keep your baby in a bassinet, lie them on their back, and be careful when they start to roll.

Going without a swaddle can be done as well, but I believe what you'll find is that occasionally your baby will startle and flail their arms, which will wake them up. With a swaddle this is less likely to happen and your baby will sleep more soundly. I'd be curious to get @anongoodnurse's thoughts on that.

@DennisJaheruddin - Any site claiming it reduces risk (of SIDS) is incorrect. There's no evidence of it influencing SIDS rates at all. Nor is there evidence that when done as per common-sense guidelines it poses any risk to the baby.

@Cdn_Dev - The infant startle response (aka Moro reflex) does, indeed, disturb the infant's sleep. The infant was used to being enclosed in the womb, which dampens the Moro reflex. What a shock it must be to be completely free, and sometimes such shocks aren't a wonderful thing. I'm very much in favor of swaddling. Agree 100% that those who use it read about it first. People can do incredibly dumb things (some of which keep ER doctors in business). (Don't get me wrong, I've done the same dumb things that I treated myself! D'uh!)
